# Standard induction proof of a sum

Tags: summation, induction

Via Induction, Prove

$$ \sum_{i=2}^n\frac{1}{i^2-1} = \frac{(n-1)(3n+2)}{4n(n+1)}$$

Comment: Is $r$ supposed to be $i$?  Assuming so, I suggest partial fractions, using $i^2-1=(i+1)(i-1)$.

Comment: Should say:  the method I am suggesting doesn't need induction.  If you want to do it inductively, Just note that $S(n)=S(n-1)+\frac 1{n^2-1}$, where $S(n)$ is your left hand sum, and use the inductive form of $S(n-1)$.

Comment: If you need to prove $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = f(n)$ by induction the key point is prove $f(n) + a_{n+1} = f(n+1)$.  So all you need to do is prove that $\frac{(n-1)(3n+2)}{4n(n+1)} + \frac 1{(n+1)^2 - 1} = \frac {n(3(n+1)+2)}{4(n+1)(n+2)}$.  If you can prove that equation you are done.

Comment: @fleablood apologies i should have added some working to show where I was at. It's that final process of showing those equivalences that I just seem to keep messing up. Do you have any tips or suggestions?

Comment: After your edit just keep going.  It's only tedious computation.  Most cancel out.  (A simple way to expand $(k+2)(k-1)(3k+2) +4(k+1)$ is to set it as $ak^3 + bk^2 + ck + d$ where $a=3; b=2\cdot 3 + (-1)\cdot 3 + 2; c= -1\cdot 2+2\cdot 2 +(-1)\cdot 2+4; d=2\cdot (-1)\cdot 2 + 4$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to prove $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = f(n)$ by induction the key point is prove $f(n) + a_{n+1} = f(n+1)$.

So all you need to do is prove that $\frac{(n-1)(3n+2)}{4n(n+1)} + \frac 1{(n+1)^2 - 1} = \frac {n(3(n+1)+2)}{4(n+1)(n+2)}$.  If you can prove that equation you are done.

As $(n+1)^2 - 1 = n^2 + 2n = n(n+2)$ putting over a common denominator look quite doable.

$\frac{(n-1)(3n+2)}{4n(n+1)} + \frac 1{(n+1)^2 - 1}=$

$\frac {(n-1)(3n+2)}{4n(n+1)}\cdot \frac {n+2}{n+2} + \frac 1{n(n+2)}\cdot \frac {4(n+1)}{4(n+1)}=$

$\frac {(n-1)(3n+2)(n+2) +4(n+1)}{4n(n+1)(n+2)}$

Okay, we want this to equal $\frac {n(3(n+1)+2)}{4(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac {n^2(3n+5)}{4n(n+1)(n+2)}$

So we just need to show $(n-1)(3n+2)(n+2) +4(n+1)= n^2(3n+5)$ and Thats straightforward:

$(n-1)(3n+2)(n+2) +4(n+1) = 3n^3 + (6+2-3)n^2 + (4-6-2+4)n + (-4 + 4)= 3n^2 + 5n^2= n^2(3n+5)$.  We are done.

.... once we do the base case of $n= 2$

We have to prove $\frac 1{2^2 -1} = \frac {(2-1)(3\cdot 2 +2)}{4\cdot 2\cdot (2+1)}$.

LHS is $\frac 13$ and RHS is $\frac 8{24}= \frac 13$.

We are done.